# This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement React Native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-play

I get this error though I have added "x86", "x86_64","armeabi-v7a","arm64-v8a" still getting following error while uploading aab on play store

This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 2.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUX9M.png)

Comment: please share a screenshot of what you are seeing on google play developer console.

Comment: What version of react-native did you use?

Comment: React native version I use id 0.59.5

Comment: Attached an image in the question @ArpanSharma

Answer (score 1):

Check your `android/app/build.gradle` file and make sure that you have the following lines:

```
...
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // If you are using 'ndk'
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
  }
  splits {
    abi {
      include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
  }
  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
          output.versionCodeOverride =
           versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
      }
    }
}
```

You have to add `"arm64-v8a", "x86_64"` in order for your apk to include the 64-bit code.

For more details and information, check these two articles: [article1](https://medium.com/@andriidrozdov/reactnative-and-android-64-bit-new-google-play-market-rules-what-to-do-584b067d6f1a) [article2](https://reactnativeforyou.com/update-your-react-native-apps-to-be-64-bit-compliant-by-august-1-2019/)

Comment: Mine is same but still getting this error. I dont know if I am missing any command.

Comment: My problem was that in splits > abi >  include - I had just `"armeabi-v7a", "x86"`, Are you sure all the 4 strings are specified in all of the three spaces?

Comment: Yes 100% sure its there